# Trying to Decrement the Sold quantity of Stock in Database

Tags: c#, sql, data-binding, datatable, datagrid

I have a batch table in Database which has columns named Quantity, Sold_qty, and Left_qty. Let's say that i have this data in table.

```
 Quantity||Sold_qty||Left_qty
  20     ||    15   ||  5
```

Then what i want to do is that when i update them let's say that if i update sold_qty with number less then already stored in DB then it should update stock and should decrease the sold Quantity and Increase the Left Quantity.

--For Example if i provide 10 for Sold_qty then as 10<15 then 15-10=5 , then 5 items from Sold_qty should be decremented and they 5 Should be added to  Left_qty. So it becomes like this below.

```
Quantity||Sold_qty||Left_qty
  20     ||    10   ||  10
```

I have data stored in Datagrid. There are multiple rows in datagrid. I have written this code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
            int difference = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text)-ordr_qty;
            textBox9.Text = difference.ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < newDt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update batch set sold_qty=sold_qty-@soldqty2 where id=@id2", con);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soldqty2", Convert.ToInt32(newDt.Rows[i]["qty"]));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id2", Convert.ToInt32(newDt.Rows[i]["batch_num"]));

                rexe = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand("update batch set left_qty=(select sum(quantity+sold_qty) from batch where id=@id3) where id=@id3", con);
                command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id3", Convert.ToInt32(newDt.Rows[i]["batch_num"]));

                command3.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
```

Comment: Is `Quantity = Sold_qty + Left_Qty`? Always?


Then just read Quanty, store new value in Sold_qty and calculated value ´(Quantity-Sold_qty)´ in Left_qty.
Anyway the question doesn't have anything with wpf, more likely with sql

Comment: No Quantity value is predefined. I have stored predefined value of Quantity

Comment: i havent said you should change Quantity. Only two other values. And better in one SqlCommand (otherwise better use TransactionScope)

Comment: How about having a table with only `Quantity` and `Sold_qty` and then a view that also calculates `(Quantity - Sold_qty) as Left_qty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposed that in DB Column name is `Quantity` and in your DataGrid.Cell (newDt.Rows[i]) you have new Value for `Sold_Qty`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newDt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var soldQty = Convert.ToInt32(newDt.Rows[i]["qty"]);
    var batchId = Convert.ToInt32(newDt.Rows[i]["batch_num"]);

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update batch set sold_qty=@soldqty2, left_qty = Quantiy - @soldqty2 where id=@id2", con);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soldqty2", soldQty);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id2", batchId );

    rexe = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```